# Implementing User Mode and Kernel Mode Switching in 64 bit UEFI OS

Tags: c++, operating-system, uefi, gdt, usermode

I am writing a 64 Bit UEFI OS ( GNU-EFI - Bootloader ). I am wondered about User Mode and Kernel Mode in OS, I have to Implement User Mode and Kernel Mode in My OS, I found some on the Internet but It won't works for me ( I thinks it is because of 64 Bit ), So How can I do it?

I am used this:

OSDEV - [Ring3](https://wiki.osdev.org/Getting_to_Ring_3)

But When I implement it in my gdt, My kernel Hangs out!

My Kernel Code :

**Commented are not my plain code that works these are copied from OSDEV - These Hangs Out the Kernel, SO I am Commented those.**

gdt.h

```
// gdt.h

#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>

struct GDTDescriptor {
    uint16_t Size;
    uint64_t Offset;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct GDTEntry {
    uint16_t Limit0;
    uint16_t Base0;
    uint8_t Base1;
    uint8_t AccessByte;
    uint8_t Limit1_Flags;
    uint8_t Base2;
    
    // These are from OSDEV, if I enable these, Kernel Hangs Out

    // unsigned int Read_Write;
    // unsigned int Confirming_Expand_Down;
    // unsigned int Code;
    // unsigned int Code_data_segment;
    // unsigned int DPL;
    // unsigned int present;
    // unsigned int available;
    // unsigned int long_mode;
    // unsigned int big;
    // unsigned int gran;

}__attribute__((packed));

struct GDT {
    GDTEntry Null; //0x00
    GDTEntry KernelCode; //0x08
    GDTEntry KernelData; //0x10
    GDTEntry UserNull;
    GDTEntry UserCode;
    GDTEntry UserData;
} __attribute__((packed)) 
__attribute((aligned(0x1000)));

extern GDT DefaultGDT;

extern "C" void LoadGDT(GDTDescriptor* gdtDescriptor);
```

gdt.cpp

```
// gdt.cpp
#include "gdt.h"


__attribute__((aligned(0x1000)))
GDT DefaultGDT = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0}, // null
    {0, 0, 0, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0}, // kernel code segment
    {0, 0, 0, 0x92, 0xa0, 0}, // kernel data segment
    {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0}, // user null
    {0, 0, 0, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0}, // user code segment    
    {0, 0, 0, 0x92, 0xa0, 0}, // user data segment
};


// This is for commented vars of GDTEntry Struct

// __attribute__((aligned(0x1000)))
// GDT DefaultGDT = {
//     {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // null
//     {0, 0, 0, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // kernel code segment
//     {0, 0, 0, 0x92, 0xa0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // kernel data segment

//     {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // user null
    
//     {0xFFFF, 0, 0, 0x00, 0xF, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, // user code segment

//     {0xFFFF, 0, 0, 0x00, 0xF, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, // user code segment
// };
```

gdt.asm

```
[bits 64]
LoadGDT:   
    lgdt [rdi]
    mov ax, 0x10 
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    pop rdi
    mov rax, 0x08
    push rax
    push rdi
    retfq
GLOBAL LoadGDT
```

**How can I enter Ring3 In 64 bit UEFI OS, Then How to Switch User Mode to Kernel Mode?**

Answer (score 0):

The GDT entry struct you reference [from OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Getting_to_Ring_3#GDT) looks like this:

```c
struct gdt_entry_bits {
    unsigned int limit_low              : 16;
    unsigned int base_low               : 24;
    unsigned int accessed               :  1;
    unsigned int read_write             :  1; // readable for code, writable for data
    unsigned int conforming_expand_down :  1; // conforming for code, expand down for data
    unsigned int code                   :  1; // 1 for code, 0 for data
    unsigned int code_data_segment      :  1; // should be 1 for everything but TSS and LDT
    unsigned int DPL                    :  2; // privilege level
    unsigned int present                :  1;
    unsigned int limit_high             :  4;
    unsigned int available              :  1; // only used in software; has no effect on hardware
    unsigned int long_mode              :  1;
    unsigned int big                    :  1; // 32-bit opcodes for code, uint32_t stack for data
    unsigned int gran                   :  1; // 1 to use 4k page addressing, 0 for byte addressing
    unsigned int base_high              :  8;
} __packed; // or `__attribute__((packed))` depending on compiler
```

This struct definition makes use of [bit fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field); note the end of each field declaration, where there is a colon followed by the number of bits occupied by the field. Despite each field having its own type declaration, fields will be packed together according to their bit width; the sum of these bit widths for the OSDev example is 64.

Your definition as written (if you include the commented fields) is 48 bytes wide. A GDT entry should be 8 bytes (64 bits) wide: see section 3.4.5 of the [Intel Software Developer's Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html). I would strongly recommend keeping the Intel manuals handy; much of the information on the OSDev wiki is out of date for x86_64, while the Intel (and AMD) manuals are continually kept up-to-date.

Regarding switching between kernel and user mode, x86_64 has dedicated instructions for system calls in [`SYSCALL`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) and [`SYSRET`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysret). I would suggest using these instructions for switches between kernel and user mode, as e.g. the Linux kernel typically does (though it also uses `IRET` under some circumstances). You can jump into user code with `SYSRET` even if the process has not made a `SYSCALL` by setting up the environment correctly (see the linked instruction reference).